# $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above. Show that the sup$S \in \overline{S}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

$S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above. Show that the sup$S \in \overline{S}$

My proof: Since $S$ is bounded above, sup$S$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, by definition, $\overline{S}$ is the smallest closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $S$. So, lets assume that sup$S \notin \overline{S}$. Also, let $k = \text{sup}S$. Now, $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus{\overline{S}}$ , which is open, as $\overline{S}$ is closed. So there exists open ball $B(k,r) \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus{\overline{S}}$ , i.e., $(k-r, k+r) \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus{\overline{S}}$. But according to definition of sup$S$ ,  $k- r/2$ is not an upper bound for $S$, thus, $\exists y \in S$ s.t. $y > k -r/2$ , but $y \leq k$ , so $y \in (k-r, k+r)$ , a contradiction. Thus sup$S \in \overline{S}$.

Can some one verify if this is correct, or if it has some loose ends which need to be tied up.

Comment: The proof seems okay to me

Comment: Unrelated: When formatting, you should put "sup" also in math mode instead of keeping it outside the dollars. You can do this by typing `\sup` inside the dollars. For example: `$\sup S \in \overline{S}$`.

Comment: @HelloWorld
After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also prove this directly (without contradiction), by using the fact that a point is in $\bar S$ if and only if every neighborhood around it contains points of $S$ (prove this using two cases: one case is that the point is in $S$ in which case it is trivial, and the second case is that the point is in the boundary of $S$).

Then, by definition of $s:=\sup S$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is some $x_\epsilon \in S$ s.t. $|x_\epsilon -s|< \epsilon \iff x_\epsilon \in B(s,\epsilon)$, so indeed $B(s,\epsilon) \cap S \neq \varnothing$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and we are done.